# JSONP cross-domain call for html giving javascript errors

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsonp

I'm making a JSONP cross-domain call through a developed API that enters html into a div. That attempt is causing key-word javascript errors (missing ; before statement, class is a reserved identifier, etc) and I really don't know where to start with this. The page can be accessed here: http://www.gounitedrealty.com/example.html
and the code can be viewed through an "Inspect Element". I really don't know where/how to start with resolving this, and am hoping someone who has had a similar project can lend a hand
or provide a suggestion.

Thanks very much

Answer (score 2):

```
www.emenu.com/api/index.php?r=api/menu&host=www.gounitedrealty.com&callback=jQuery16406947022259701043_1317694125388&_=1317694126263:1
```

is missing the most important part of JSONP, the JSON. It's HTML.

Comment: so I can't pass html back inside the json? The html is in data.content: $data = array('id' => Yii::app()->session['id'], 'html' => $content);              
$json = CJSON::encode($data);
header("Content-type: application/json");  
echo $_GET['callback'] . ' (' . $json . ');';

Comment: jsonlint.com <= it must pass that

Answer (score 2):

That's because it's invalid json. It's HTML.